# Deque's methods and the methods inherited from Queue

Tags: java, collections

As stated in the **[Deque's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)**, the `Last`-methods (`addLast`, `removeLast`, etc...) are totally equivalent to the `Queue` methods. So it's not clear to me why they declared the `Last`-methods in the `Deque` interface. Why wouldn't just use the `Queue`'s methods in the `Deque` interface and declare the only `First`-methods?

Comment: in Queue you just insert from front and delete from rear while in Dequeue, using api, you could either delete from head or rear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `addLast` makes your intent clearer than `add`. Code that contains calls to `addFirst` and `addLast` is easier to understand than code that contains calls to `addFirst` add `add`.

Comment: What confused me is the inheritance Deque from Queue. Yeah, I got that it makes more transparent to use the methods, but inheritance....

Comment: @St.Antario You can argue that Deque extends the behavior of Queue, since it allows to add and remove from both ends, while Queue only allows to add to the end and remove from the start.

Comment: Ah, ok. Any Deque might be used as a Queue. With your last comment now it's clear. Thank you.

Comment: Deque was added in Java6, Queue was already present, so it's likely that the type relationship is for compatibility reasons as much as for logical reasons.